# pass parameter when clicking on link without using ?id=xxx

Tags: javascript, php, html

Is there any way to pass parameter by just clicking on a link, in condition of link does not handle the parameter for example

```
<a href='example.php?id=1'>M</a>
```

I don't want to use the `?id=1`

is there a way to do this? I want the parameter to be passed to next page without form and link parameter when clicking on a link.

So I can handle the parameter on the next page, not on the same page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest - you could create a form with a hidden input and send it on click on that link. Here is the code (using jQuery):

```js
$('.submit-form').click(function(){
  //add the value to be sent to the input in the form
  $('#link-extra-info input').val( $(this).data('submit') );
  
  //the href in the link becomes the action of the form
  $('#link-extra-info').attr('action', $(this).attr('href'));
  
  //submit the form
  $('#link-extra-info').submit();
  
  //return false to cancel the normal action for the click event
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="link-extra-info">
  <input type="hidden" name="p" value="0">
</form>

<a href="page.html" class="submit-form" data-submit="1">Link text 1</a>
<a href="page2.html" class="submit-form" data-submit="2">Link text 2</a>
```

Comment: This is by far the most effective and efficient solution, thank you. not only i can create mass amount of link with similar behavior and your notes helped me to adjust your JavaScript to accommodate mine. thanks

Answer (score 3):

#### Example 1

You can use a `data-*` parameter and Ajax for it.

```
<a class="example_anchor" href='example.php?' data-id="1" >M</a>

<script>

$(".example_anchor").on("click", function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var id = $(this).data('id');

$.ajax({
    url: your_url,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { id: id },
    error: function (msg) {
        // Error handling
    },
    success: function (msg) {
        // Success handling
        if (msg == true) {
             alert("You will now be redirected.");
             window.location = "//your_redirect_link/";
        }
    }
});


});

</script>
```

#### Example 2

You can use Function in `onclick` of tag `<a>` passing parameters

```
<a href='#' onclick="yourfunction(1)">M</a>

<script>
    function yourfunction(id1)
    {
        alert(id1);
    }
</script>
```

#### [JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/narcX/)

Comment: AJAX keeps him on the same page, does not take him to the URL in the link.

Comment: I actually want to go to that url rather then staying on the same page, is it possible to fix a little bit so i will go to the page? i am not so familiar with ajax

Comment: @ankitsuthar that redirect does not pass the variable. You end up calling the target script twice: the first time sending the variable and getting nothing from the script, the second time not sending any data.

Comment: To be clear, I also consider AJAX the best for this kind of interaction. But you need to get the result and use it in the same page, and the OP had something else in mind for his situation.

Answer (score 1):

Potentially creative solution: use a cookie.  HTML would be:

```
<a href="link.html" onclick="passVariable(this)">Link</a>
```

With some JS

```
<script>
function passVariable(url) {
    document.cookie = "id=1";
    window.location.href = this;
}
</script>
```

Then on the page you're navigating to, use some JS to retrieve the cookie:

```
<script>
    function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
        var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
        for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                c = c.substring(1);
            }
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
</script>
```

Could do an AJAX call to get associated data after parsing the cookie value.